# Meses me los muestra en inglés los quiero en español

Tags: java, localdate

Este es mi código en Java :

```
private static String devuelveTextoDia(LocalDate dia){
    String res = "";
    Integer diaValor = dia.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    Month mes = dia.getMonth();
    switch(diaValor){
    case 1:
        res = "lunes de " + mes ;
        break;
    case 2:
        res = "martes de " + mes;
        break;
    case 3:
        res = "miércoles de " + mes;
        break;
    case 4:
        res = "jueves de " + mes;
        break;
    case 5:
        res = "viernes de " + mes;
        break;
    default:
        res = "fin de semana de " + mes;

    }

    return res;
}
```

El objetivo es que muestre por ejemplo "lunes de Octubre" , el mes en español. Pero claro , yo soy consciente de que al llamar al método getMonth() , los meses me van a salir en inglés en este caso saldría , lunes de OCTOBER. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo para que saliera en español los meses?
Gracias de antemando

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba:

```
 String mes = dia.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es","ES"));
```

Comment: Gracias si que me sirvió , funciona. No me acordaba de que estaba el método getDisplayName . Saludos